# Aliasing issue with GPUImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I get weird black aliasing on a transparent text GPUImagePicture blended with a base GPUImagePicture with a GPUImageView as the final target. This is what I'm doing:

```
textOverlay = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.rootViewController.previewImageTextOverlay];
GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *textBlend = [[[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init] autorelease];
[upstreamOutputFilter addTarget:textBlend];
[textOverlay addTarget:textBlend];
[textBlend addTarget:gpuPreviewImageView];
[textOverlay processImage];
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [kevinharringtonphoto.com](http://www.kevinharringtonphoto.com/photos/i-m4Hrt6L/0/M/i-m4Hrt6L-M.png))</sub>

How do I remove the aliasing?

I want this (which I get by stacking two UIImages):
[image]
<sub>(source: [kevinharringtonphoto.com](http://www.kevinharringtonphoto.com/photos/i-QqgWnhg/0/M/i-QqgWnhg-M.png))</sub>

Comment: This might be an issue with premultiplied alpha, as mentioned in issues here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/768 and here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/907 . I may not be handling that right in images with some antialiased edges.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but no luck on either of those. I tried changing this line to use premultiplied alpha: cgImageFromBytes = CGImageCreate((int)currentFBOSize.width, (int)currentFBOSize.height, 8, 32, 4 * (int)currentFBOSize.width, defaultRGBColorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated and found this to be a bug with GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter. The problem is that the shader code doesn't take into account the pre-multiplied alpha of the second image.

Here is a quick fix:

Replace

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb, textureColor2.rgb, 
                        textureColor2.a * mixturePercent), textureColor.a);
```

With:

```
if (textureColor2.a == 0.0) {
   gl_FragColor = textureColor;
} else {
   gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb, textureColor2.rgb / textureColor2.a,
                           mixturePercent * textureColor2.a), textureColor.a);
}
```

There is probably some nice way to do this with the shader that doesn't involve branching, but this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nuoji, this works for me, but i am need set opacity value

```
 filter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
 [filter setMix:1];
```